# Extract text from pdf file by pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

i am facing an issue in pdf reading.

```
public class GetLinesFromPDF extends PDFTextStripper {

    static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, String> auMap = new HashMap();
    boolean objFlag = false;

    public GetLinesFromPDF() throws IOException {
    }

    /**
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = null;
        String fileName = "E:\\sample.pdf";
        try {
            int i;
            document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new GetLinesFromPDF();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            stripper.setStartPage(0);
            stripper.setEndPage(document.getNumberOfPages());

            Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
            stripper.writeText(document, dummy);

            // print lines
            for (String line : lines) {
                //System.out.println("line = " + line);
                if (line.matches("(.*)Objection(.*)")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    withObjection(lines);
                    //System.out.println("iiiiiiiiiiii");
                    break;
                }
                //System.out.println("uuuuuuuuuuuuuu");

            }
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.writeString()
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("textPositions = " + string);

        // System.out.println("tex   "+textPositions.get(0).getFont()+ getArticleEnd());
        // you may process the line here itself, as and when it is obtained
    }
}
```

in need a output like 
My pdf have some title, we need to skip the same.

pdf file content is

[image: pdf output and pdf content]

how to extract text as in separate formats as specified.

thanks in advance.

Comment: *"how to extract text as in separate formats as specified."* - That is far from specified. First of all, how can the headings be recognized? Do they really all start with "MyHeading" or "SubHeading"? Or are they all prefixed with "heading :" or "subheading :"? Or is there a mix of these variants?

Comment: in some pdf its there but not in other pdfs.

Comment: Ok, then explain the criteria by which your headings can be recognized and we'll help you find out if and how that can be codified.

Comment: A sample text does not clearly convey *criteria by which your headings can be recognized*.

Comment: thank you for your support.
due to some security issues i'm presenting a sample pdf content.
some text (eg company name  logo etc)
Objection 1
   Department: abc
  this is an objection sample which need to aganest the rule of property 
Response
  the users need to obey this rule
Objection 2
  department : xyz
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Response
   response of lorem ipsum is very good
like it goes till last page of pdf, i think its simpler need to check the key as Objection Department & response

Comment: issue is in certain other pdf
1) this is an objection sample which need to aganest the rule of property 
  users are being adasdkjasdlkjkjkjljkjkjkjkjjadjakdjskjdaksjdkjjadskajs
  (here the reponse in bold letters)the users need to obey this rule
2) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   (here the reponse in bold letters)response of lorem ipsum is very good
i need to identify if letter is in bold the its response
can you please suggest a solution, checking writeString override method of PDFTextStripper.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot recognize in your comment what is fixed text and what is dynamic. Please explain more clearly and add that explanation to your question (there is an [edit] link underneath to allow editing it).